# Is Java SE required to install Netbeans even if you have JDK installed on the system?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and am installing Netbeans 12. The installer prompts to install **Java SE** (and Java EE) and bunch of other stuff.

Do I need really need to install that (Java SE and Java EE) since I already have the JDK installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install the Java version that comes with Netbeans. You just need to select the Java installation you want to use in the Netbeans installer.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs it appears you only need the JDK and Java EE but I am not on my home system to verify.
[NetBeans 12 Docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Apache+NetBeans+12.0)